# How to dynamically update an RX Observable?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-kotlin

(Working in RxKotlin and RxJava, but using metacode for simplicity)

Many `Reactive Extensions` guides begin by creating an `Observable` from already available data.  From [The introduction to Reactive Programming you've been missing](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754), it's created from a single string

```
var soureStream= Rx.Observable.just('https://api.github.com/users');
```

Similarly, from the frontpage of [RxKotlin](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxKotlin), from a populated list

```
val list = listOf(1,2,3,4,5)
list.toObservable()
```

Now consider a simple filter that yields an `outStream`,

```
var outStream = sourceStream.filter({x > 3})
```

In both guides the source events are declared *apriori*.  Which means the timeline of events has some form

```
source: ----1,2,3,4,5-------
out:    --------------4,5---
```

How can I modify `sourceStream` to become more of a pipeline?  In other words, no input data is available during `sourceStream` creation?  When a source event becomes available, it is immediately processed by out:

```
source: ---1--2--3-4---5-------
out:    ------------4---5-------
```

I expected to find an `Observable.add()` for dynamic updates

```
var sourceStream = Observable.empty()
var outStream = sourceStream.filter({x>3})

//print each element as its added 
sourceStream .subscribe({println(it)})
outStream.subscribe({println(it)})

for i in range(5):
    sourceStream.add(i)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I think that's called a PublishSubject.

Comment: Ah ok, yes this does look like what I need.  Thanks,, would never have found that :)

Comment: You *might* want to look at `PublishRelay` from https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay/ because that does not stop emitting events after an error event.

Comment: Wonder why the tutoirals don't start with such publishers.  I mean you can't be reactive without having something to react to

Comment: Because `Subject`s are generally to be avoided/rarely needed. http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx

Comment: @AdamHughes Subjects are difficult to control and could be easily abused. But indeed, lost of build-in operator use subject for convenience aswell. Just follow the observable contract when you use subjects. And try not use RxBus as much as possible.

Comment: I'm new, but how could I solve my problem without a subject?  If I'm testing an application, and I want it to "pop" an update every 5 seconds, how else can I do it other than this Publish subscribe business?  Can someone post an answer to this question that doesn't involve a Subscriber?

Comment: @AdamHughes It depends on how the events are created. Do you want some kind of [event bus](https://lorentzos.com/rxjava-as-event-bus-the-right-way-10a36bdd49ba)?

Comment: Nor sure what I need (am just starting out).  Maybe I'll just figure it out as I go and get more invested into real projects.  My goal for this little project was simply to build an event processing pipeline, and wanted to push source updates through it every few seconds (intead of reading from a stored list for example)

Answer (score 3):

> I'm new, but how could I solve my problem without a subject? If I'm
>   testing an application, and I want it to "pop" an update every 5
>   seconds, how else can I do it other than this Publish subscribe
>   business? Can someone post an answer to this question that doesn't
>   involve a Subscriber?

If you want to pop an update every five seconds, then create an Observable with the `interval` operator, don't use a Subject. There are some dozen different operators for constructing Observables so you rarely need a subject.

That said, sometimes you do need one, and they come in very handy when *testing* code. I use them extensively in unit tests.

[To Use Subject Or Not To Use Subject?](http://davesexton.com/blog/post/To-Use-Subject-Or-Not-To-Use-Subject.aspx) is and excellent article on the subject of Subjects.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I need.  I will read that article too